# How do I run the first n lines of a script?

Tags: bash, script, shell-script

I have a script file with hundreds of lines. Say I only want to run the first 10 lines. I could do

```
head -n 10 file.script > file10.script
chmod +x file10.script
./file10.script
```

I'm sure there must be a one-liner way to do this though. What would that look like?

Comment: Exit (on line 11)?

Comment: I'll bet a debugger would be useful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right; it's possible with a one-liner via process substitution.

```
bash <(head -n10 file.script)
```